# How to add ecw image to GeoServer(ImageMosaic)?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, ecw

I'm trying to add ECW to ImageMosaic and have an error.
At first i'm add storage:
[image: add store]

Then a click button "Relase":
[image: relase]

and get this error:
i.stack.imgur.com/6HJ8j.png

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@522006f6 on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
    at 

...

org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:366)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$8.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:280)
    at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
    at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException: Can't transform envelope.
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1247)
    at org.geoserver.data.util.CoverageStoreUtils.getWGS84LonLatEnvelope(CoverageStoreUtils.java:306)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverageInternal(CatalogBuilder.java:949)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:899)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:859)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:356)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: No transformation available from system "EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]" to "GeographicCRS[WGS84(DD)]".
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(DefaultCoordinateOperationFactory.java:389)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.java:258)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.transform(CRS.java:1245)
    ... 115 more
```

**gdalinfo**:

```
Driver: ECW/ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
Files: L:\FME\LC81520312015277LGN00_bands_432.ecw
Size is 7921, 8041
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (7889674.242117469200000,5291538.802705821600000)
Pixel Size = (41.385913793827569,-41.482549429561317)
Metadata:
  COLORSPACE=RGB
  COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=4
  VERSION=2
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 7889674.242, 5291538.803) ( 70d52'26.94"E, 42d51'56.20"N)
Lower Left  ( 7889674.242, 4957977.623) ( 70d52'26.94"E, 40d37'49.44"N)
Upper Right ( 8217492.065, 5291538.803) ( 73d49' 8.35"E, 42d51'56.20"N)
Lower Right ( 8217492.065, 4957977.623) ( 73d49' 8.35"E, 40d37'49.44"N)
Center      ( 8053583.154, 5124758.213) ( 72d20'47.65"E, 41d45'27.85"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Description = Red
  Overviews: 3960x4020, 1980x2010, 990x1005, 495x502, 247x251
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Description = Green
  Overviews: 3960x4020, 1980x2010, 990x1005, 495x502, 247x251
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Description = Blue
  Overviews: 3960x4020, 1980x2010, 990x1005, 495x502, 247x251
```

Comment: Looks like your data has some strange referencing (`EngineeringCRS[Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit]`). Can you show the metadata for the file you are trying to load (e.g. from gdalinfo or similar)?

Comment: ECW file: drive.google.com/open?id=0BwCz6eAdhIl2TGxGOW93ZUcxSUU or you ask different data?

Comment: I'm not going to open a random link. Edit the question to include the output of gdalinfo on that file.

Comment: BradHards, add gdalinfo